# Better alternative to try(:output).try(:data).try(:name)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

"output" is a serialized OpenStruct.

def **title**
  try(:output).try(:data).try(:title)
end

What would be better? :)

Comment: You should give much more information before asking such an abstract question.

Comment: The question was clearly clear to those who answered the question clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or simply this:

```
def title
  output.data.title rescue nil
end
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that, if there is something wrong on that chain, you won't notice it after it's too late =P

Comment: Though this works well for some cases, it is bad advice without precautions.  `rescue` handles exceptions, and is by-nature much slower

Answer (score 4):

Referring to [this blog](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/) you might find it better to use the &. operator like below for ruby version > 2.3.0;

```
 output&.data&.title
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def try_chain
  yield
rescue NoMethodError
  nil
end

def title
  try_chain { output.data.title }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Thoughtbot just talked about [this on their blog](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/190940474/swallow-nil), using what they call it's a Shallow Nil:

```
def swallow_nil
  yield
rescue NoMethodError
  nil
end
```

So, in their example, they could do something like:

```
campaign = swallow_nil { supporter.politician.campaign }
```

Or, in your case,

```
def title
  swallow_nil { output.data.title }
end
```

However, be aware that any of your bugs will also be swallowed and would be hard to find, specially since it traps every NoMethodErrors, which would be caused from other parts of your code (although if you use testing, this helps a lot).

Another approach would be to [use andand](http://andand.rubyforge.org/), where your code would be then

```
def title
  output.andand.data.andand.title
end
```

Not as clean as the swallow_nil one, but probably best to not just ignore everything.